# Text boxes don't undo properly in Mac OS (10.10.4) and Safari (8.0.7)

Tags: support, bug, safari, undo, mac

If I type a sentence that has an autocorrect, the undo (Command-Z) removes the whole sentence instead of just undoing the last changes (including the autocorrect change). I have used the contact form on this website and that form works fine. The question and answer boxes have this problem.

Comment: Huh, I didn't even know we had undo/redo functions built into our editor. As an aside: why do we have our own built into our editor? Do they do something that the normal browser's functions can't handle? (also, reproduced on Chrome - this isn't browser-specific)

Comment: @animuson so should this be changed to feature request asking to remove those buttons from the editor?

Comment: [Related issue here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323401). You have only found ONE way that undo/redo is broken. Cutting and pasting is just as broken (if not more so), but I think that removing the buttons may solve all these issues.